# How to call a method of the component that Navigator has mounted?

Tags: react-native

I want to call a method from the component (scene) that the Navigator has instantiated once the `onDidFocus()` function is called.

This is how I instantiate the Navigator:

```
<Navigator
    initialRoute={{ name: 'Login' }}
    renderScene={ this.renderScene }
    configureScene={(route, routeStack) => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight}
    onDidFocus={(route) => route.component.onFocus()}
    />
```

And this is my `renderScene()` method:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {

    if(route.name == 'Login') {
        route.component = <Login navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}  />
    }

    return route.component
}
```

But `route.component.onFocus()` is `undefined` since (I presume) `route.component` is not a reference to the instance that was mounted of `Login` but a reference to the type `Login`.

So how can I get a reference to the instance of the component that was mounted?

How can I call a method of the component that has been mounted when the `onDidFocus()` method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @farwayer suggested, calling a function from the component is bad practice since it's coupled code.

In the end I used our own Event Bus to notify any interested party that the transition had ended.

```
onDidFocus(){
    EventBus.ref().emit('NAVIGATOR_TRANSITION_END')
}

render() {
    return (
        <Navigator
            ...
            onDidFocus={ this.onDidFocus }
            />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling component methods directly is a bad practice. If you simply want to catch moment when component activated you can override `componentDidMount()` method.

Or in more complex situation you can call `setState()` in parent component and pass new props to `Login`. Something like this:

```js
<Navigator
    initialRoute={{ name: 'Login' }}
    renderScene={ this.renderScene }
    configureScene={(route, routeStack) => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight}
    onDidFocus={(route) => this.setState({currentRoute: route})} />

renderScene(route, navigator) {
     return <Login
         currentRoute={this.state.currentRoute}
         navigator={navigator}
         {...route.passProps} />
}
```

and then catch new props in `Login` component with overriding `componentWillReceiveProps()`.

Comment: Your code doesn't work since `renderScene` is called before `onDidFocus` and hence `this.state.currentRoute` is `undefined`.

Comment: It was concept about you can change state of parrent component and pass any new props to child component

Comment: Even if you pass `route` to the component (or any other prop) it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Then what problem is? Why do you need to call child component method on `onDidFocus` callback?

Comment: The problem is described in my question.

Comment: Ok if you *really* want it you can use `ref` callback https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html